# Best way to do a ruby process as a daemon

Tags: ruby, debian, daemons

What is the best way to do a ruby process as a background system daemon in Debian?

These daemons are telecom billing process read from many database sources, which write one at a time and to a log file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're asking for opinions, which are off-topic, in a very broad question. What have you tried? If you haven't tried, where have you searched and why didn't those help answer your problem? As is you show no effort, which is essential. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm trying to learn best way and the best practices to do a background daemon from the ruby point of view.

Comment: Hey, @TinMan, stop being a bully. Again, this isn't that bad of a question. You people need to seek other hobbies. I get it, you have 90,000 reputation points, you can downvote every question made on stackoverflow today. Fact is, you're discouraging new members from joining the community.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do:

```
Process.daemon(true, true)
```

Comment: Now, tell "What is the best way" as OP asked ... ;-)